# Super slow Windows ADK(Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit) installation. What is wrong?

Tags: adk

I have already downloaded the Windows ADK and started installing it yesterday.
As of now, the progress is still 17%.
Is this normal? probably not!
What is wrong? and what should I do about it?

[image: Progress of the Windows ADK installation]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Stop the installation, then check the SMART data of your disk and do `chkdsk`. Check the Event Viewer for error messages that might apply.

Comment: @harrymc Okay, I will try that, thank you